# Adapt content of a scrollView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uicollectionview, scrollview

Hi everyone I'm following this apple tutorial on SwiftUI .. I got to the point where Apple explains how to make a horizontal scrollView with images.

[image]

```
struct CategoryRow: View {
    var categoryName: String
    var items: [Landmark]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(categoryName)
                .font(.headline)
                .padding(.leading, 15)
                .padding(.top, 5)

            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(items) { landmark in
                        CategoryItem(landmark: landmark)
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 185)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the photo I posted you can see 2 complete images and one not. I would like you to be able to decide how many complete images to display (for example 4 full images within the screen) and that they fit all devices

(ex ..

- iPhone 8 -> 4 image on screen
- iPhone 12 -> 4 image on screen

)

---

In a nutshell I need to know how to adapt the content of a `ScrollView` to be displayed on different devices such as it happened with `UIKit` using the `UICollectionView` and in the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method I inserted

```
.init (width: collectionView.frame.size.width / 4, height : collectionView.frame.size.height)
```

How can I get this using SwiftUI?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but if you want to display data in a scrolling view while limiting the rows and columns, that calls for a `LazyGrid`. This is the corollary to a `CollectionView` in `UIKit` If you don't want a scrolling view, then Federico Zantello's recent write up on his [FiveStars.blog].(https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/flexible-swiftui/) may help.

Comment: @Yrb I was already trying to work with LazyHGrid but the problem is that I cannot assign an adaptation value for each type of iphone device (eg iphone 8, iphone x, iphone pro max etc.) to the displayed elements so that they are also displayed optimally on different sized screens

Comment: Except you can have the `LazyHGrid` adapt to the size of the screen by making the `GridItem` `.flexible`. If you want a four column layout, then making all the `GridItem`s `.flecible` will space them according to the amount of space they need, and if they are in a standard `.frame`, they will all take the same amount of space. You have shown us what you DON'T want, but not what you DO want.

Comment: @Yrb Yes I need to adapt the contents of a LazyHGrid to any device

Comment: Do you want it to scroll? Do the items need to be even or can they be all different sizes? Do you simply want ONLY 4 images in the view at a time, with no scrolling? All of that is easily doable.

Comment: @kAiN Can you like to the tutorial or a download from Apple of the Xcode project? Also: do you want to only show like 4 images on the screen but you can still scroll to the side, or do you want only 4 columns and then the content scrolls vertically?

Answer (score 0):

Yous could use the geometry reader to figure out how big or small the device is and tailor the orientation of the pictures to that
To use GeometryReader:

```
var body -> some View {
GeometryReader { proxy in
  if proxy.size.width > 324.0/2.0 { 
   // Your landmark view but with 4 pictures
    MyBigView()
  } else {
   // Your landmark view but with 3 pictures
    MySmallView()
  }
}
}
```

For reference, here are the watch resolutions:

40mm: 394×324
44mm: 448×368
38mm: 340×272
42mm: 390×312
Divide by 2.0 to get their values in points instead of pixels.